# Ubuntu print screen don't work when toolbar icon scrolled down

Tags: icons, screenshot

I can not get the screenshot when the UGet Download Manger Toolbar icon is scrolled Down like this:

[image]

But in the Firefox in this situation when i press PrtSc button it closes the toolbar icon and run the screenshot like this:

[image]

Thanks for your attentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, taking a screenshot with an open menu will not work directly because your application menu will not handle the print screen key. However, you still can obtain a screenshot when you use a timer. Set a small delay before the actual screenshot is taken. Use the delay to pull down the menu.

Stepwise instructions:

- Load the Screenshot app using the application overview.
- Set the options to your liking. Importantly, set a few seconds delay after "Grab after a delay of"
- Click "Take Screenshot". The dialog disappears and you return to your previous application. Pull down the menu and wait a little bit until the delay you set has passed.
- After the delay, a dialog of the screenshot tool pops up again, prompting you to save the screenshot.